# watchPosition() refreshes the full map not only the marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-markers

I have a code but the problem is the watchposition() is relaoding the full map.What I want is a code to refresh only marker's position. Here's what I've done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Geo Location</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas{ height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSuccess(position) {
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lang=position.coords.longitude;     
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);
    var mapOptions = {zoom: 4,center: myLatlng};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng,map: map});     
}
function onError(error) {
alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
var watchID=navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,onError{timeout:30000 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use setPosition()

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419317/html5-geolocation-watchposition-is-reloading-full-map-not-only-position

Answer (score 0):

use `setPosition()`
sth like this?
https://plnkr.co/edit/UgCEnQ?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var marker, map;

    function initMap() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lng = position.coords.longitude;
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 18

          });



          if (marker != undefined) {
            marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
          } else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map
            });

          }


        });
      }



    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's an android app and when I test it on mobile it doesn't use device's gps.